# how to load leadbolt web banner ad in unity project?

Tags: unity-game-engine, banner-ads, leadbolt

In one of my unity projects, i want to implement leadbolt banner ad. I'm having trouble because I'm not familiar with unity.

I have implemented other ads but not getting any idea for setting banner ad.

How does one add a leadbolt banner ad to unity?